# How to track clicking on a link in email sent from apex

Tags: apex, email

We are sending an email with a link to a license file from apex code to an existing customer. I would love to see if a person clicked on that link and take some actions based on that. Is it even possible to implement with salesforce?

The first idea comes to my mind is to create a redirect where using api I will call salesforce database and retrieve further information. And redirect information will be stored in a custom object. Have anyone tried something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did exactly the same thing you are asking. You can create a visualforce page with custom controller which is tracking visiting that link.  You have to send a link which points to page for tracking a click and then redirects user to correct licence file.

Flow have to be like this:

- user go to handlelink page
- handlelink page tracks a click
- handlelink redirects user to licence file

For example:

/apex/handleLink?id=55

Vf page:

```
 <apex:page action={!redirect}>
 </apex:page>
```

Contoller:

```
public class handle_controller{

    public PageReference redirect(){

        String licenceid = apexpages.getcurrentpage().getparameters().get('id');

        //select a licence file with that id
        //update this licence file which has a custom field isclicked__c 
        //and after that redirect user to this licence attachement file

        Pagereference pg = new pagereference('/servlet/....');
        Pg.isredirect(true);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea of written.